# find matching strings in file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a list of strings in file A that I am trying to match with the first column of file B & output all fields in file b that have exact match. Here is the awk script that I am using but it keeps giving me errors. I can't seen to figure out the problem. Any help is appreciated.

```
while read line
{
    awk '{($1~/'"$line"'/) print $1}' fileB
} 
done < fileA
```

Comment: This task can be done only with `awk`, and only in **StackOverflow** you can find several hundred of solutions to your exact problem.

Comment: That is miles away from an awk script. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 3rd Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Quick!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense as an awk script:

```
{($1~/'"$line"'/) print $1}
```

I think you're trying to see if the first column (`$1`) contains `$line`.  If this is the case, your match expression needs to go *outside* the braces, and you don't need the slashes (`/`) around the regex, like this:

```
$1 ~ '"$line"' {print $1}
```

And you can save yourself some quoting by passing in a variable to awk like this:

```
awk -v line="$line" '$1 ~ line {print $1}'
```

Comment: Thank you larsks so much for your help. The script works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

without examples of input/output, just guess what you want, you mentioned ( exact match) try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$1 in a' fileA fileB
```

Comment: I hope that downvoter could give some explanation, so that I can learn things. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/^&/p#' fileA|sed -nf - fileB
```